# Arduino sketch repeats an instruction even when it doesn't have too

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm programming an Arduino Sketch that in general terms is a calculator that uses 4 numeric systems: decimal, binary, octal and hexadecimal.
When I ask the user for the numeric system he's gonna input the desired system (1 for decimal, 2 for hexadecimal, 3 for octal and 4 for binary) with a keypad, then, after receiving this input, the arduino prints on an LCD the chosen system. But these portion of the code seems to repeat itself indifinitely, without executing the part where the numbers and operands are inputted. I can't input numbers that aren't 1, 2, 3 or 4 and if I press one of these numbers it prints its system, completely ignoring the previous input.

I've tried boolean switches to indicate the program to not run that portion of the code if it has been executed previously but it doesn't seem to work

This is the portion of the code that receives the input and validates it. The switch case repeats itself other 3 times in the other 3 cases, changing the numerical system that is printed.

```cpp
void loop()
{
  char base = calcuShift.getKey();
  if (base != NO_KEY && (base == '1' || base == '2' || base == '3' || base == '4')) {
    switch (base) {
      case '1':
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Sistema");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Decimal");
        delay(3000);
        lcd.clear();
        break;
```

After the switch case it must execute the following code:

```cpp
char key;
if (digitalRead(A0) == HIGH) {
  key = calcuShift.getKey();
} else {
  key = calcu.getKey();
}

if (key != NO_KEY && 
    (key=='1' || key=='2' || key=='3' || key=='4' || key=='5' || key=='6' || key=='7' || key=='8' || key=='9') && 
    base == '1') {

  if (inicio == false) {
    num1 = num1 + key;
    int numLength = num1.length();
    lcd.setCursor(15-numLength,0);
    lcd.print(num1); 
  } else {
    num2 = num2 + key;
    int numLength = num2.length();
    lcd.setCursor(15-numLength,1);
    lcd.print(num2);
    final = true;
  }
```

Obviously including other if conditionals that vary depending on the variable "base" (the one the user inputs at the beginning). If it's 1 (decimal) it accepts numbers 0 through 9, if it's 2 (hexadecimal) it accepts numbers 0 through F etc.
The user inputs his numbers with the variable key. The object calcuShift is just the normal keypad in shift mode, with the letters and other two operands instead of numbers and the multiplication and division operands replaced by power and root operands.

I want my calculator to receive the wanted numeric system, receive numbers in such system and make operations with these numbers, returning an answer in the previously chosen system, but instead just sticks to the input of the variable "base" that dictates the numeric system used.

Answer (score 0):

An Arduino sketch is intended to execute `loop()` as fast as possible forever and ever.
Anything that is intended to run once after startup should go into `setup()`

Typically, you define a sort of `finite state machine` that behaves different whether a user is supposed to enter the number base code or a digit or an operator key. And it stores previous input (the current state) in some global or static variables.

At the end of `loop()` there's no "program" finish, but it just has checked for all currently possible state changes, stored them and *eventually* updated the display.

And as `loop()` is fast enough to react immediately on any button press, it will normally simply do nothing, as no new key is pressed.

If your code does something repeatedly forever but should do that only once, you simply don't store the fact that this was done already. (Or you use the reset button as user interface and allow that "choose number base" only for the `setup()` phase )